# Joomla save function with ajax update

Tags: component, ajax, view

I would like to call a controller function and after that I would like to update my view with an ajax call.

Therefore I call my controller function from an ajax script using this url:

`url: "index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=component.save"`

Everything seems fine, but I cannot access my form inputs in the controller.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$data = $jinput->get('jform', 'default_value', 'filter');
```

`$data` stays empty.

When I call the function from a normal Joomla button in the form, everything is fine and all values from the form are available in the controller.

I would like to call my controller function and afterward I would like to update my view with an ajax call.

Comment: Are you using a post method for the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to try it like this:

```
$data  = $this->input->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using joomla 3, you can use jquery for this functionality:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); // make sure jquery is loaded
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.post('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=component.save', 
jQuery( "#yourformid" ).serialize(), function(data, 
statustxt){ jQuery('#resultdiv').html=data; })
</script>
```

This should return the result to an element . Docs for jQuery.post() is found here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. The post-functionality should add the data from your form as post-variables for joomla to read. To see all incoming post-variables in php write

```
print_r($_POST);
```